# Can Android Emulator run on cloud like Amazon AWS with HAXM

Tags: android, amazon-ec2, android-emulator, haxm

We know that Android Emulator can run super fast with Intel HAXM. https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

I am trying to get Emulator running on cloud.

But i when i tried installing HAXM on Amazon (AWS-EC2 )windows BOx it failed stating it not supported.
Are there any image on AWS where HAXM is supported . Also are there any other cloud service provider which support HAXM

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable KVM to speed up android emulation on Linux. However, KVM requires Intel-VT/AMD-V support and neither is provided by AWS. However, there is an alternative method to get Intel-VT/AMD-V support on AWS.

Currently, I am using [Ravello](http://www.ravellosystems.com) to run android emulators on AWS, as their nested hypervisor can enable Intel-VT/AMD-V support on top of AWS. The performance increase is significant, however, you will not have hardware accelerated graphics.

You can take a look at this blog: [How to run the Android Emulator (with Hardware Acceleration) on Amazon EC2 and Google Cloud](http://www.ravellosystems.com/blog/android-emulator-on-amazon-ec2-and-google-cloud/) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.
Genymotion recently added their Android VD as an Amazon Machine Image - https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01MREUQPU

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increase android emulator speed then it is better to use genymotion software. HAXM is related with the hardware graphics in your PC so, i don't think HAXM should support in cloud VM.

Comment: Sadly Genymotion didn't work on AWS. It gave error while starting up VirtualBox (Xen Enviroment not supported ). I guess it something to do with Virtualization .